# Pre Get Posts - Difference between conditional() and $query->conditional()?

Tags: conditional-tags, pre-get-posts

This may be a poor question but inside `pre_get_posts()` is there any real difference between `$query->conditional()` versus just adding the `conditional()` ? Take the following example:

```
/** Themes Pre Get Posts **/
function theme_pgp( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_home() ) {
        // Run Conditional 1
    }

    if( is_home() ) {
        // Run Conditional 2
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'theme_pgp' );
```

For readability I prefer to use the second conditional but I often see code use the first so my question is: inside the `pre_get_posts` function / action / filter - is there ever a case where this may return different results, meaning 1 conditional runs but not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a big difference... most of the times.

`is_home()`, just like any other conditional tag, check **main query**.

`$query->condition()` check the query object that is passed by action, that can be a a completely different query, because `pre_get_posts` is called for **all** queries.

As example, let's assume you are viewing a **singular post**, and inside `single.php` you have:

```
$q = new WP_Query( array('nopaging'=>true) );
```

Now let's assume in `functions.php` you have:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function ($query) {
    if( $query->is_home() ) {
       // conditional code
    }
} );
```

The hooked callback will run when action is triggered by both main query and secondary query.

However, for main query, conditional code does **not** run, because you are in singular post view, but when fired by secondary query conditional code **will** run, because that secondary query object is of home type.

So it's not wrong to use `$query->is_home()` nor `is_home()`, they are just different, you should choose the one or the other based on the results you want to obtain.

However, when the query object passed by action is the main query, the 2 ways are identical, so if you want to check only main query objects, use one or another makes no difference:

```
function theme_pgp( $query ) {
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return; // only main query
    }

    // here using is_home() or $query->is_home()
    // does not make any difference
}
```